# How do I add a new date column with constant value to a Spark DataFrame (using PySpark)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to add a column with a default date ('1901-01-01') with exiting dataframe using pyspark?

I used below code snippet

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
  strRecordStartTime="1970-01-01"
  recrodStartTime=hashNonKeyData.withColumn("RECORD_START_DATE_TIME",
  lit(strRecordStartTime).cast("timestamp")
  )
```

It gives me following error 
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`1970-01-01`'
Any pointer is appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

strRecordStartTime = "1970-01-01"

recrodStartTime = hashNonKeyData.withColumn("RECORD_START_DATE_TIME", F.to_date(F.lit(strRecordStartTime)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use python native `datetime` with `lit`, I'm sorry don't have the access to machine now.

```
recrodStartTime = hashNonKeyData.withColumn('RECORD_START_DATE_TIME', lit(datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created one spark dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(["Ravi","Gaurav","Ketan","Mahesh"], StringType()).toDF("Name")
```

Now lets add one new column to the exiting dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
import dateutil.parser
yourdate = dateutil.parser.parse('1901-01-01') 
df2= df1.withColumn('Age', lit(yourdate)) // addition of new column
df2.show() // to print the dataframe
```

You can validate your your schema by using below command.

```
df2.printSchema
```

Hope that helps.